# Changing two select options value via javascript

Tags: javascript

there are two option controls in a website:

```
<select class="operator" name="operator" id="operator">
    <option value="0">Entekhab Operator</option>
    <option value="1">Irancell</option>
    <option value="2">Talia</option>
    <option value="3">HamraheAval</option>
</select>


<select class="card" name="chargeCard" id="chargeCard">
   <option value="0">Entekhab Sharj</option>
</select>
```

When a user changes the first one by clicking on that (and selecting an option), the second one will also change...as you see in the above code, the second option has no value and will get some values after clicking on the first one

My problem is that I have to change them via javascipt in my android program

I tried with the following:

```
document.getElementById("operator").value=2
```

and this way i changed the first one.

But the second one does not change and dose not get values! What should I do for the second option to change as well?

Comment: _"please visit www.gasharj.ir ..."_ **No!**.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe i didnt explain my question very well. i changed the value of the option but i needed something like stimulating the change event.
this code solved my problem:

```
$('#operator').trigger('change');
```